# How to get a tuple to conform to sequence?

Tags: swift, for-loop, tuples, protocols

I have the following code in Swift 5:

```
func iceCreamFlavors() -> (String, String, String) {
    return ("Chocolate", "42", "Vanilla")
}

for index in iceCreamFlavors(){
    print(index)
}
```

I'm simply trying to iterate over the elements in the returned tuple. However, I get the following error: `error: for-in loop requires '(String, String, String)' to conform to 'Sequence'`

How can I get a tuple to conform to sequence? Do I need to extend the Sequence protocol? If so, how should I do so?

Comment: You cannot _not_ know what that function returns.

Answer (score 2):

In your example function you are returning 3 elements and no other options are possible. If you want a different number, use [String] as a result, i.e.

```
func iceCreamFlavors() -> [String] {
    ["Chocolate", "42", "Vanilla"]
}
```

---

Returning an array will allow you to iterate its elements:

```
let flavors = iceCreamFlavors()
print(flavors.count)
for flavor in flavors {
    print(flavor)
}
```

Comment: What about if I want to return different data types? I assume I need a tuple for this, right?

Comment: @purpleprince you can but `Any` has no count property and or conform to sequence to be able to iterate its elements. If you need to return different types you can create a generic method. But considering you are a beginner it will be much harder for you to implement/understand how it works.

Comment: @purpleprince this is turning out to be an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a dynamic function that 1) returns different data types and 2) can return anywhere from 1 to 10 elements. Since a different number of elements is returned each time, I want to be able to iterate through each element without knowing the number of elements beforehand. (thanks for all the help!)

Comment: @LeoDabus, I'm somewhat familiar with generics... what would my generic method have to conform to in order to make it iterable?

Comment: You can have a generic type that conform to sequence but all elements would usually  be of the same type. What you are probably looking for is to structure your data. Without more details it will always be just a wild guess.